# In Xcode, how do we delete older physical devices?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode12

I am using XCode and was trying some apps using iPad Air, iPad Pro, iPhone SE, etc, and when I tried another iPhone, it said the number of maximum devices have been reached and gave an error.

How would we delete a device and let another device be used?

Comment: I had a paid one but that one had used some even older devices such as iPhone5 or 6, and iPad 4... so this one I am trying is a new, different account (which is not a paid developer account)

Comment: I know that they have made it quite hard to remove devices from the free accounts.  With a paid account, I have achieved this by going onto chat with the support team and asking for older devices to be removed.  I never managed to find an easy way of managing it directly.

Answer (score 2):

When I sign in ( with paid one)
I can remove devices like below.

- After sign in developer account follow: `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Devices` finally choose the device which you remove and click disable button. It will be removed.
- By the way there are limited number devices which can be added as you said in devices as well as same for certificates.

Apple says : "If you are the Account Holder, you can reset your list of development devices each year using Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. You can register up to 100 of each device type for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year. At the start of your new membership year, Account Holders, Admins, and App Managers will be presented with the option to remove listed devices and restore the available device count to 100 when first signing in to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.

Although you may remove a device from your account during the year, it will continue to count against your device limit. When resetting your list, make sure to remove all devices you no longer use for development before adding any new devices."

[image]

---

Note : There isn`t specific information for free accounts or device limitation as far as i search Apple documents. To erase your device from an account permanently : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201274

Comment: @nonopolarity i edited my answer and whenever i find something new i will revise it again for community as well. This is a nice question everyone can wonder.

Comment: thank you... " There is any specific information for free accounts"... you mean "there isn't"?

Comment: @nonopolarity yes i do